# Error when copying empty dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code to copy the values in dynamic ranges one after the other. This code fails if one of the dynamic ranges is empty. Is there a way around this?

```
Dim r1, r2, r3 As Integer

Range("Abandoned").Copy
Range("C110").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

r1 = Range("Abandoned").Cells.Count

Range("Prod75").Copy
Range("C" & 110 + r1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

r2 = r1 + Range("Prod75").Cells.Count

Range("Prod5075").Copy
Range("C" & 110 + r2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

r3 = r2 + Range("Prod5075").Cells.Count

Range("Prod2550").Copy
Range("C" & 110 + r3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Check to see if it's empty first?

Comment: I used if statement to first check the cell count in the range, but that also is not working

Comment: Please explain *exactly how and where* your code fails.

Comment: Prod 2550 is an empty range in this case. The code fails after Range("Prod2550").Copy line. I get error 1004, application or error defined error. Only the first 3 ranges are copied

Comment: Don't check the count, check to see if it's `Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

Put your named ranges in an array.

Loop the array testing each if it is Nothing.

Then place the assign the values directly to the first cell that is empty.

```
Dim nameArr()
nameArr = Array("Abandoned", "Prod75", "Prod5075", "Prod2550")
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your output sheet

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(nameArr) To UBound(nameArr)
        If Not Range(nameArr(i)) Is Nothing Then
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Range(nameArr(i)).Rows, Range(nameArr(i)).coloumns).Value = Range(nameArr(i)).Value
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks...where do I input the location where i want to copy these values. Also, I am getting a subscript out of range error when I run this

Comment: on which line do you get the error?  This will put the data in the first empty cell in column C  If you want to clear the values in column C before, add: `.Range("C110:C" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents` after the `With ...` line.

Comment: If it is on the With line then check the spelling of the worksheet.  It was supposed to be changed to you output sheet name, hence the note to change it to your output sheet.